# How to extract specific length urls from text file using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, extract

I am trying to extract the list of URLs from the text file using notepad++ and have tried different expressions as well, but it is replacing the URLs instead of extracting them.

```
href=&quot;https://prnt.sc/2oz4yt&quot; class=&quot;external-link&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;https://prnt.sc/4om4fj&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
```

I have large text file like mixture content inside it but I want to extract only prnt.sc list from it

```
https://prnt.sc/2oz4yt
https://prnt.sc/4om4fj
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: Interesting... the ampersands are valid parts of URLs but are obviously junk in this case. You might need to run a Find/Replace on those first before trying any regex.

Comment: yes, whatever the best solution, waiting for the answer! i have more than 250 prnt.sc URLs in 1 file contain same mixture of tags from where i want to extract the specific domain URL with specific length!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\G(?:(?!https://prnt.sc/\w{6}).)*(https://prnt.sc/\w{6})?`
- Replace with: `(?1$1\n)`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\G                      # restart from last match position
(?:                     # non capture group
  (?!                   # negative lookahead, make we haven't after:
    https://prnt.sc/      # literally
    \w{6}                 # 6 word characters
  )                     # end lokkahead
  .                     # any character
)*                      # end group may appear 0 or more times
(                       # group 1
    https://prnt.sc/      # literally
    \w{6}                 # 6 word characters
)?                      # end group, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists
  $1        # keep it
  \n        # line break, you could use \r\n for windows end of line
)           # end condition
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! just solved my problem by using your suggestion and 1 change is by deselecting .matches newline.

Comment: @Raza: You're welcome, glad it helps.